# point of intersection using matrices

Tags: calculus

1. Find the point of intersection between the line connecting $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and the line connecting $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} \phantom -3 \\ \phantom -0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

ok, so I found the normal vector of each, then took the cross product \begin{pmatrix}6\left(-6\right)-\left(-2\cdot \:4\right)&-2\left(-2\right)-\left(-3\left(-6\right)\right)&-3\cdot \:4-6\left(-2\right)\end{pmatrix} to get \begin{pmatrix}-28&-14&0\end{pmatrix} how is this wrong?

2. Consider the line
   \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ -7 \end{pmatrix}+ t\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
   Find the smallest possible distance from the line to the origin.
   How would I do this second question as well?

Comment: You found the normal vector of each? Each of what? If you want to use matrices, I suggest you first solve the equation $\vec{p}(t_1)=\vec{q}(t_2)$ where $$\vec{p}(t)=(2,3,6)+(0,1,3)t$$ $$\vec{q}(t)=(1,2,1)+(1,-1,-1)t$$ The line $\vec{p}(t)$ connects $(2,3,6)$ to $(2,2,3)$ while $\vec{q}(t)$ connects $(1,2,1)$ to $(3,0,-1)$. For the second part, I suggest you minimize $\|\vec{r}(t)\|^2$ over $t$, where $$\vec{r}(t)=(2,3,-7)+(-1,-2,1)t$$

Comment: It must be $q(s)$ instead of $q(t)$.  For the second part, calculate the length of orthogonal projection of $(2, 3, -7)$ in direction $(-1,-1,1)$ and use Pythagoras.